# How do I get a div created in js to fill the screen after clicking on a dynamically created td?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a jeopardy style game where if you click on a dynamically created td containing the dollar amount pertaining to a question, the question (already obtained from Jeopardy API) is placed as an innerText inside a dynamically created div element. After clicking on the td, I want the div to animate and fill the entire screen.

This is a little snippet.

```
handleClick(e) {
        let targetID = e.target.id;
        if (this.lockboard) return;
        for (let x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
            for (let y = 0; y < this.height - 1; y++) {
                if (targetID.includes(`${y}-${x}`) && targetID) {
                    this.lockboard = true;
                    let newDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
                    let clickedTD = document.getElementById(`${y}-${x}`);

                    console.log(clickedTD);
                    newDiv.innerText = this.clues[x][y].question;

                    newDiv.classList.add('zoom-in');
                    console.log(this.clues[x][y].question);
                    console.log(this.clues[x][y].answer);
                }
                this.lockboard = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

handleClick is the callback passed to an event  Listener on the dynamically created td in an instance method.

The .zoom-in class in CSS has the following code:

```
.zoom-in {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(1) translate(100%, 100%);
    transition: transform 3s;
}
```

TDLR: I guess I just don't know how to animate the div to blow up and fill the whole screen after clicking the TD

Answer (score 0):

The class `zoom-in` can expand the element it targets to full screen and height.

```
.zoom-in {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: width 3s, height 3s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add property background-color. Not sure if this could solve a problem.

```
.zoom-in {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: width 3s, height 3s;
}
```